# Count by groups (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 5 years of stock date. I need to do this: take years 1, 2 and 3 What is the probability that after seeing k consecutive ”down days”, the next day is an ”up day”? For example, if k = 3, what is the probability of seeing ”−, −, −, +” as opposed to seeing ”−, −, −, −”. Compute this for k = 1, 2, 3.  I have played with groupby and cumsum, but can't seem to get it right.

For example:

```
group1 = df[df['True Label'] == "-"].groupby((df['True Label'] != "-").cumsum())
```

| Date | True Label |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-02 | + |
| 2019-01-03 | - |
| 2019-01-04 | + |
| 2019-01-07 | + |
| 2019-01-08 | + |

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bit of logic:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['+','-'], 1000))
sm = s.groupby((s == '+').cumsum()).cumcount()

prob = (sm.diff() == -3).sum() / (sm == 3).sum()
prob
```

Output:

```
0.43661971830985913
```

Details:

Use `(s == '+').cumsum()` to create groups of '-' records,  `groupby` and `cumcount` the elements in this group, the first element is the '+' and cumcount starts with zero.  There fore '+--' will become 0, 1, 2.  Now, take the difference to find out where '-' turns to '+'.

If this is equal to -3 then we know this group has three minus and is followed by a '+'.

Check `sm==3` to get to all number of times you hand '---', `sum` then divide.

Comment: ah yes! This is what I was looking for. Thanks so much! I appreciate the explanation also.

Comment: @Neonleon You're welcome. Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Comment: Guys does it really work as intended for you? I think strict operator `==` in `prob = (sm.diff() == -3).sum() / (sm == 3).sum()` results in ignoring some sequences. For example if I would have sequence: `s = pd.Series(['+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+'])` I would expect probabily to be 1/3 (two sequences `- - - -` and one `- - - +`).

Comment: @LockeErasmus You are correct, if you interpreting the problem this way.  Here I am only counting once if the group of - are atleast three.  If the groups of - are more than three, you could count the group multiple times.

Comment: @LockeErasmus I think good correction would be: `prob = (sm.diff() <= -3).sum() / (sm >= 3).sum()`